# I have 2 series of data in a Highchart and I only need to show one of them while ensuring that both series labels and values show in the tooltip

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have 2 series of data in one graph where one is shown and the other is hidden, while having both series labels and values show in the tooltip?

Comment: would this example also work for highstock? http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/fDNh9/184/